# forced alignment with aneas

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am trying to build a simple dataset for speech recognition using aneas, following the instruction [here](https://medium.com/@klintcho/creating-an-open-speech-recognition-dataset-for-almost-any-language-c532fb2bc0cf). However I'm stuck at the forced alignment, here is my code

```
from aeneas.executetask import ExecuteTask 
from aeneas.task import Task 
import os
import numpy

config_string = "task_language=eng | is_text_type=plain | os_task_file_format=json"
task = Task (config_string=config_string)

task.audio_file_path_absolute = "D:/documents/AI/open_door.mp3"
task.text_file_path_absolute = "D:/documents/AI/open_door.txt"

task.sync_map_file_path_absolute = "D:/documents/AI/syncmap.json"

ExecuteTask(task).execute()

task.output_sync_map_file()
```

Which gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aeneas\ffprobewrapper.py", line 222, in read_properties
    proc = subprocess.Popen(
  File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aeneas\audiofile.py", line 357, in read_properties
    properties = FFPROBEWrapper(
  File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aeneas\ffprobewrapper.py", line 233, in read_properties
    self.log_exc(u"Unable to call the '%s' ffprobe executable" % (self.rconf[RuntimeConfiguration.FFPROBE_PATH]), exc, True, FFPROBEPathError)
  File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aeneas\logger.py", line 351, in log_exc
    raise raise_type(raise_message)
aeneas.ffprobewrapper.FFPROBEPathError: Unable to call the 'ffprobe' ffprobe executable : [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\documents\AI\forced_alignment.py", line 9, in <module>
    task.audio_file_path_absolute = "D:/documents/AI/open_door.mp3"
  File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aeneas\task.py", line 120, in audio_file_path_absolute
    self._populate_audio_file()
  File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aeneas\task.py", line 241, in _populate_audio_file
    self.audio_file.read_properties()
  File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aeneas\audiofile.py", line 363, in read_properties
    self.log_exc(u"Unable to call ffprobe executable", None, True, AudioFileProbeError)
  File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\aeneas\logger.py", line 351, in log_exc
    raise raise_type(raise_message)
aeneas.audiofile.AudioFileProbeError: Unable to call ffprobe executable
[Finished in 0.4s]
```

Intuitively, I think it is because of the file paths, but changing it doesn't seem to work. I have never worked with python before so show me where I did wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure it's because ffprobe isn't in your system's environmental variables.

Have you tried running python -m aeneas.diagnostics and is ffprobe in your path? Look into adding programs to your Path/system environment variables.

Comment: The `python -m aeneas.diagnostics` tip is worth its weight in gold!